# How do I communicate ground control computer to Flight Controller Unit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, raspberry-pi4, px4, qgroundcontrol

I am curious on how to communicate QGroundControl on my laptop to the FCU, pixhawk4, which is connected to my raspberrypi 4, running ubuntu 18.04. I am using the PX4 toolchain as my flight controller unit and MAVROS as my companion computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of workarounds for this but the simplest you can do is:

1. Connect both Host and pi with the same network.
2. use [mavlink-router](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/simulation/#use-mavlink-router) to route packets to your host's ip and simply open QGC. In most cases QGC automatically detects the connection.